# How do I create a sphere using symbolic math and fimplicit3 function in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

```
clear all
syms x y z
sphere = x^2 +y^2 +z^2;
fimplicit3(sphere == 25), xlim([-12 -5]),ylim([-12 5]),zlim([-12 12])
```

This is my current code. It's meant to be a sphere at center (-5,5,12) with a radius of 5. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If the center is at (xc,yc,zc) and the sphere has radius r, then:

```
xc = -5;
yc = 5;
zc = 12;
r = 5;
f = @(x,y,z) (x-xc).^2 + (y-yc).^2 +(z-zc).^2 - r^2;
fs = fimplicit3(f,[-10 10 -10 10 7 17])
```

Notice your function handle must give a function equal to 0.
Notice also that symbolic variables are not defined.
The limits given in the second argument of the `fimplicit3` function are the limits for the x, y and z variables. You can change then accordingly.
The result is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I actually ended up figuring it out via another method, using xlim ylim and zlim. However, I very much appreciate your help.